# Making the Mac more left hand friendly

Tags: macos, notifications, accessibility

I am a left handed Mac user and I find that some features are not left hand friendly. In particular Notifications is quite bothersome. Most of the time my cursor is over near the left hand edge of the screen; that is the part of the workspace I tend to operate from and when an email notification comes up I have to move my cursor nearly across the full diagonal of the screen to get to the banner before it disappears. I quite often don’t get it. If there was a way to make the Notifications appear on the left hand side of the screen that would be great. Does anyone know of a way to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't change the location where Notification Center Alerts and Banners appear. This is a huge gripe of mine as well, and I highly encourage you to complain about this issue to Apple here:

http://www.apple.com/feedback/macosx.html

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure whether this is really a left vs right-handed thing.
All English speakers read left to right, so have a tendency to put our work left-aligned.
I am right handed, but work left-aligned, the same as you, so the distance to any Banner notification is about the same.

To give you more time to reach a Notification, you could either change Notification type to Alert rather than Banner, in Prefs > Notifications [needs setting for each Notification type]

[image]

or you could change the length of time Banners stay on screen - using Terminal.

`defaults write com.apple.notificationcenterui bannerTime [time in seconds]`
eg `defaults write com.apple.notificationcenterui bannerTime 5` [which is what I think the default is]

You can return to clean defaults at any time by using
`defaults delete com.apple.notificationcenterui bannerTime`

Each change requires that you relog.

Source: [OS X Daily - Change How Long Notification Banners Persist for in OS X](http://osxdaily.com/2014/01/29/change-notifications-banner-time-mac-os-x/)